Clarification about the decorator of the step() method of the stochastic gradient descent class
In the SGD class of pytorch, the step() method has the decorator _use_grad_for_differentiable:
@_use_grad_for_differentiable
def step(self, closure=None):
...

Usually I would expect the no_grad decorator to be used instead.
I found no information about _use_grad_for_differentiable and have no idea what it does. The source code for the decorator can be found in the file torch/optim/optimizer.py, but it has no docstring or helpful comments, and the code is cryptic (for me). For completion, I paste it here:
def _use_grad_for_differentiable(func):
 def _use_grad(self, *args, **kwargs):
     import torch._dynamo
     prev_grad = torch.is_grad_enabled()
     try:
         # Note on graph break below:
         # we need to graph break to ensure that aot respects the no_grad annotation.
         # This is important for perf because without this, functionalization will generate an epilogue
         # which updates the mutated parameters of the optimizer which is *not* visible to inductor, as a result,
         # inductor will allocate for every parameter in the model, which is horrible.
         # With this, aot correctly sees that this is an inference graph, and functionalization will generate
         # an epilogue which is appended to the graph, which *is* visible to inductor, as a result, inductor sees that
         # step is in place and is able to avoid the extra allocation.
         # In the future, we will either 1) continue to graph break on backward, so this graph break does not matter
         # or 2) have a fully fused forward and backward graph, which will have no_grad by default, and we can remove this
         # graph break to allow the fully fused fwd-bwd-optimizer graph to be compiled.
         # see https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/104053
         torch.set_grad_enabled(self.defaults['differentiable'])
         torch._dynamo.graph_break()
         ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
     finally:
         torch._dynamo.graph_break()
         torch.set_grad_enabled(prev_grad)
     return ret
 functools.update_wrapper(_use_grad, func)
 return _use_grad

My question(s): what is the role of this decorator? Why not simply use no_grad() instead? And, finally, should I be using this decorator in my custom optimizers?

I don't understand the inner workings of PyTorch well enough to write an answer, but I might give the following hints: (1) Indeed, earlier versions of PyTorch optimizers used @no_grad – see for example this change in the Adam optimizer. (2) the @_use_grad_for_differentiable decorator was introduced with the pull request Add initial support for differentiable optimizers whose goal it was to enable "optimization of optimizers", thus meta-optimization/learning (if I understand correctly).
